# Even though the tag exists it says nothing found

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to make a command that pulls from the furry.booru API but the tag (which does exist) just says "nothing found".

I am some what new to this API stuff for discord.py so please help.

The code I tried is below.

```py
@bot.command(aliases=['fb'])
async def furrybooru(ctx, *, tags: str):
      await ctx.message.delete()
      """Searches furry.booru for images of hentai"""
      await ctx.channel.trigger_typing()
      tags = strip_global_mentions(tags, ctx)
      try:
           data = requests.get(
            "https://furry.booru.org/index.php?page=dapi&s=post&q=index&json=1&limit={}&tags={}"
            .format(limit, tags),
            headers=header).json() #index.php?page=dapi&s=post&q=index&deleted=show
      except json.JSONDecodeError:
          await ctx.send("Couldn't find anything :(")
          return

      count = len(data)
      if count == 0:
          await ctx.send("Couldn't find anything :(")
          return
      image_count = 4
      if count < 4:
          image_count = count
      images = []
      for i in range(image_count):
          image = data[random.randint(0, count)]
          images.append("https://furry.booru.org//samples/{}/sample_{}?{}".format(
              image["directory"], image["image"], image["id"]))
    #await ctx.send("nsfw.results", ctx).format(image_count, count, tags, "\n".join(images))
      await ctx.send(images[0])
```

Comment: Is it failing because of `JSONDecodeError` or because `count == 0`? You should use different messages so you can tell which it is.

Comment: it is because of JSONDecodError @Barmar

Comment: Then the API isn't returning valid JSON. You should look at the text of the response to see what it's returning.

Comment: @barmar im sorry to say but i really dont know how. sorry. im too new to this.

Comment: `print(requests.get(...).text)`

Comment: You should also print the URL to make sure it's what you intended.

Comment: when i did it i got a long list of some html code some .json if you want i can send it to you over on discord or another way of contact @barmar

Comment: post it to pastebin.com

Comment: [this is the pastebin link](https://pastebin.com/jLC4nVvh) @Barmar

Comment: The link no longer works.

Comment: alright i will make a new one [here ya go](https://pastebin.com/0cWvHGdF) @Barmar

Comment: It still doesn't work. **This page is no longer available. It has either expired, been removed by its creator, or removed by one of the Pastebin staff.**

Comment: oh well is there any other way of sending this to you?

Comment: If there's HTML code before or after the JSON, it's a problem with the API.

Comment: it says cloudflare so im assuming theres no way of fixing it

Comment: Do you have a link to the API documentation so we can check if you're calling it correctly?

Comment: yes i do @Barmar [here it is](https://furry.booru.org/index.php?page=help&topic=dapi)

Comment: They're broken, the API is going through the CAPTCHA used by the website: See https://furry.booru.org/index.php?page=forum&s=view&id=3719

Comment: AH alright well thank you for your help @Barmar